# Xen HW virtualization on Power architecture?

Tags: xen

[Xen - Hardware-assisted virtualization, allowing for unmodified guests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xen#Hardware-assisted_virtualization.2C_allowing_for_unmodified_guests)

The wikipedia page says Xen has HW virtualization for Intel and AMD CPU's.

**Q:** Does Xen supports HW virtualization on Power architecture?

ps.: regarding: [IBM and Linux: The next billion dollars](http://www.zdnet.com/ibm-and-linux-the-next-billion-dollars-7000020757/)

Comment: http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_FAQ_Compatibility#Which_architectures_does_Xen_support.3F

Comment: can you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

No, Xen does not support Power architecture.  Quoting http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_FAQ_Compatibility#Which_architectures_does_Xen_Project_support.3F

> Xen Project currently runs on the x86, x86_64 and ARM architectures. As of Xen 4.3 Xen requires at least x86 64-bit for the hypervisor. Xen used to be supported on IA64 (Itanium) but that support was dropped as of Xen 4.2 and Linux v3.14. On x86 Xen Project requires a "P6" or newer processor (that's any Intel or AMD x86 CPU purchased in the last seven years). Multiprocessor and multicore machines are supported, including support for Hyper-Threading (SMT). Support for x86/64 is available since Xen 3.0. We hope to add other architectures such as PPC.